# Date column from year and month columns postgreSQL / SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with integer columns 'year' and 'month' that I want to replace by a single date column. I create a new column using:

```
ALTER TABLE test01 ADD COLUMN date_column DATE
```

and can update the column values using:

```
UPDATE test01
    SET date_column = '2001-12-28'
```

But I want to generate a date using the year and month columns.

How can I accomplish this in SQL (postgreSQL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`make_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) does what you want:

```
UPDATE test01
    SET date_column = make_date(year_col, month_cl, 1);
```

Comment: works! An overview of functions can be found here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html